# Blank Excel fields creating problem in Creating TableView using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, excel

I was about to take input from an excel and using conversion tool in arcpy I have to convert the excel to table in a gdb. But when I used this Excel to table tool, I found that there are columns named 'F34', 'F35' etc which in excel does not hold anything.

How do I either remove those columns from the table or avoid those columns while doing conversions?

Comment: If you only select the columns you want and copy paste into a new blank excel i think the empty columns will disappear.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `field_info` parameter of [Make Table View](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-table-view.htm) to set the fields as HIDDEN. But it is easier to drop them after import:

```
import arcpy
table = r'C:\data.gdb\sometable'

fields_to_drop = ['F35','F36']
#or
fields_to_drop = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(table) if f.name.startswith('F3')]
#or
fields_to_drop = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(table) if len(f.name)<4 and not f.required]
#or something else

arcpy.DeleteField_management(in_table=table, drop_field=fields_to_drop)
```

Comment: Hello Bera Thanks for sharing it. I understand what you have described. But only one thing I am not getting is the hard coding part. In case if you have something to remove the hard coding. I mean in future I may get some blank columns which may not be F35 or F36.

Comment: You did not include this information in your original question. You would have to iterate over all values in each column and check if they are empty